# WCF ServiceHost crashes mono when client disconnects on timeout

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mono

I am getting the below error when client disconnects after the timeout and then server tries to return the result: -

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Object.__icall_wrapper_mono_delegate_end_invoke(object,intptr)
>     at (wrapper delegate-end-invoke) .end_invoke_bool__this___Message&_IAsyncResult(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message&,System.IAsyncResult)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DuplexChannelBase.EndTryReceive (System.IAsyncResult result, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message& message) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Channels/DuplexChannelBase.cs:196 
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerLoopManager.TryReceiveDone (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher/ChannelDispatcher.cs:596 
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.Invoke(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)
>     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging/AsyncResult.cs:210 
>     at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:856 
>     at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1211

Answer (score 0):

The error typically indicates that the channel communicated with that client has an error, and then the server tries to communicated with the channel, for example **Chatting application**.

When we use the WCF duplex mode. you could use

```
Channel.Closing+=new EventHandler(Channel_Closing)
```

to listen the status of the client.

I suggest you use the Heartbeat packet to indicates the client status, and then handle the errors/process the logic.

Comment: Abraham, not sure if it helps. Lets say, I manage to catch it on the server side code, what is the next action I will take?
The error is occurring in mono where it is trying to get hold of the caller and return response which is already disconnected